# Как добавить новый столбец в существующую таблицу sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть база в которой есть таблица users (в ней уже много строк) со столбцами name | age | city , мне необходимо добавить новый столбец status и туда сразу поместить значение 0 для всех строк. Подскажите какой запрос это реализует. непойму можно ли сразу через ALTER TABLE добавить его значение 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно так же, как и при создании таблицы, вы можете указать в конце определения столбца значение по умолчанию с помощью `DEFAULT`.
Что-то такое должно получиться:

```
ALTER TABLE users
  ADD status INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
```

Там есть в этом сценарии некоторые ограничения на значения типа дат, но на строки и числа вроде бы ограничений нет.